# Count of the given query with City and Profile Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

```
select b.ProfileName,c.City from tblJobs as a 
inner join tblProfile as b on b.ID = a.ProfileID
inner join tblCity as c on c.CityID = a.CityID
```

O/P

```
Profile Name        City

Gym Manager         Mumbai  
Personal Trainer    Mumbai  
Personal Trainer    Mumbai  
Personal Trainer    Bengaluru
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like all you're missing is a `group by` clause and a call to `count`:

```
SELECT     b.ProfileName, c.City, COUNT(*)
FROM       tblJobs AS a 
INNER JOIN tblProfile AS b ON b.ID = a.ProfileID
INNER JOIN tblCity AS c ON c.CityID = a.CityID
GROUP BY   b.ProfileName, c.City
```